# Document always gives: Promise { <state>: "pending" }

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

Ok this is the story that is making me loose my mind from 48 hours.

I have  a movies news website with preview thumbnails that need to be loaded from a json endpoint and be updated every hour. I can load the json content to populate the element with id `#movie-trailers` and it works perfectly.

**The trick to fire a video play event on mouseover of a specific element of the preview thumbnail.**

As long as I do it with thumbnails already printed into the starting DOM, the jquery works flawlessly, but if I fire the `displayRelated()` function and I populate the `#movie-tralers` element, every dynamically generated thumbnail doesn't play the mp4 file!

If I do `console.log($('video',this).get(0).play();)` i get the message `Promise { <state>: "pending" }`

Here is the code:

```js
$(document)
  .ready(function () {
    displayRelated();
    setInterval(displayRelated, 3600000);
  })
  .ajaxStop();
function displayRelated() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/path/to/my/json",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function (data) {
      var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
      $.each(obj, function (index, value) {
        var element = jQuery.parseHTML(value);
        $("#movie-trailers").append(element);
      });
    },
  });
}
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".thumb", function () {
  $("video", this).get(0).play();
});
$(document).on("mouseleave", ".thumb", function () {
  var video = $("video", this).get(0);
  video.currentTime = 0;
});
```

And here is a standard thumbnail:

```
<div class="thumb">
  <video muted loop preload="none">
    <source src="/path/to/video.mp4" type="application/x-mpegURL">
  </video>
</div>
```

**EDIT:
Sorry guys, it's official that I'm a bit dumb. The error was before all our eyes but nobody noticed it including me: the source tag's mime type is totally wrong!**

For those whop had my same problem it's enough to set the source tag as

```
<source src="/path/to/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

Comment: The `play` function returns a promise.

Comment: Why are you logging the result of `.play()` to the console in the first place?  What do you expect that to be and why?  It sounds like there's no problem at all and just a false expectation of the return value of a function.  (Or, if there is a problem, this false expectation is distracting you from addressing it.)

Comment: "As long as I do it with thumbnails already printed into the starting DOM, the jquery works flawlessly" — There is, presumably, *some* difference with those and the ones you are dynamically generating. Maybe a URL is wrong somewhere. I'd look to the Network tab to debug it.